# Is it ok to write a CW answer extracted from a comment of some user?

Tags: discussion, comments, community-wiki

Suppose I have seen an answer to a question by a user X.

Suppose another user Y leave a comment under X's answer. This comment received good number of up votes (6 as of now). This comment is not explicitly mentioned in any other answers

Is it OK if I can make this comment as a CW answer giving appropriate credit for the user Y?

That question already has many answers, along with an accepted answer.

Comment: A related older post: [Questions answered in a comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/493).

Comment: @MartinSleziak but that question already have many answers, along with an accepted answer...

Comment: Yes, it's encouraged. Usually I do so after suggesting to the commenter to write an answer and waiting for a few days. Conversely it occurred to me to write an answer after being encouraged to do so after a comment (preferably cw if it's just a reference).

Comment: @YCor "and waiting for a few days." +1 Ok..

Comment: PS I was mainly addressing the case of a question answered in comments. You should do this only if there is good reason to promote the question to an answer. For instance, if it's a good alternative answer. Maybe also if it fixes or improves the existing answer, in case the answerer doesn't want to modify the answer. Or possibly for some other reason (would you point to the post(s) you have in mind?)

Comment: @YCor I am referring to comment https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119699/grothendieck-topology-for-a-non-small-category/119814#comment307645_119708

Comment: Isn't it fine as a comment?

Comment: @YCor The point that sheafification functor may not exists for a large category seems (to me) to be an important thing and that is what Urs said in his comment.. It has not mentioned in any of the answer, not even in Urs's answer.. So, I thought of making a CW answer.. Is that fine or should I leave it as it is?

Comment: Sure, this seems to be a good complementary answer then.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's perfectly okay to do this, Praphulla. Usually that would be seen as a service to the community.